# how can I change velocity of a child of a physics.group in phaser.js?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a game in Phaser which looks like that:
[image]

player has to catch the eggs, so the eggs (which are made from `gameState.eggs = this.physics.add.group();`) have a certain `velocity` while on the ramp, but then once they're off the ramp, i want to authomatically `setVelocity()` to one with 0 for x coordinate, instead of just shooting across the screen.

Here's my egg generating function:

```
function eggGen() {
let num = Math.random();

let xCoord, yCoord, eggDirection, eggAnimation, velocityX

if (num < .5) {
    xCoord = 100;

    eggDirection = 'eggLeft';
    eggAnimation = 'rollingLeft'
    
    velocityX = this.velocityX;
    
    if (num < .25) {
        yCoord = 232;

    } else {
        yCoord = 382;
    }
} else {
    xCoord = 700;

    eggDirection = 'eggRight';
    eggAnimation = 'rollingRight';

    velocityX = -(this.velocityX)

    if (num < .75) {
        yCoord = 232;

    } else {
        yCoord = 382;
    }
}

let egg = gameState.eggs.create(xCoord, yCoord, eggDirection).setVelocity(velocityX, this.velocityY).setScale(.6);

if (egg.x > 220 && egg.x < 580) {
    egg.setVelocity(0, this.velocityY);

}

egg.anims.play(eggAnimation);
}
```

the last conditional is what i hoped would do the magic, but it doesn't do anything. To clarify, `eggGen` function is called inside `this.time.addEvent();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your code *(and assuming arcade physics is used)*, I would:

Just check in the `update` function, *of the scene,* if a egg is "on the ramp" and has a *x-velocity*  of `0`

```
  function update(){
       // ...
       gameState.eggs.getChildren().forEach(egg => {
           if(egg.velocity.x > 0 && (egg.x > 220 || egg.x < 580)) {
               // ... stop velocity.x or set the whole velocity new
               egg.velocity.x = 0;
           }
       });
       // ...
  }
```

**Here a mini Demo:**
*It just covers the basics*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 300,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: { 
            debug: true,
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    },
    banner: false
}; 

let objectGroup;

function create () {
    objectGroup = this.physics.add.group();
    this.time.addEvent({ delay: 500, callback: createObject, callbackScope: this, loop: true });
}

function createObject(){
    let spawnLeft = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 1);
    let obj = this.add.rectangle(spawnLeft ? 0 : config.width, 0,  10, 10, 0xff0000);
    this.physics.add.existing(obj);
    
    objectGroup.add(obj);
    obj.body.setVelocity((spawnLeft ? 1 : -1) * 75, 30);   

}

function update(){
     if(!objectGroup)
         return;
   
     objectGroup.getChildren().forEach(obj =>{
         if(obj.body.velocity.x > 0 && (obj.x > 100 && obj.x < 150) || (obj.x > config.width - 150 && obj.x < config.width - 100) ){
             // Just to keep the same speed, even after changing direction
             let speed = obj.body.velocity.length();
             obj.body.velocity.x = 0;
             obj.body.velocity.y = speed;
         }
     });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: despite your example showing that it works, it doesn't for me. probably has to do with the fact that `eggGen` is called within `this.time.addEvent();`

Comment: @chylinski, I would like to help but it is, hard t say without seeing your code. Is there maybe an error in the browser console?

Comment: @chylinski when using the `addEvent`, are you passing the context over `callbackScope: this,` ?

Comment: yes, i was passing `callbackScope: this`, you were right the first time, i fixed it in `update` like you suggested, but with a slightly different solution. thanks a lot!